# Speech to text with Titanium Appcelerator (for Android)

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I want to implement an Speech to text plugin in Titanium Appcelerator using JavaScript. 
Which API should be used for the same?

I came across [this link](https://github.com/mumumu/Titanium-Android-VoiceRecognition). It is useful for the plugin development in Java. If anyone have knowledge about it, please tell me if I can use it to develop the plugin in JavaScript and how can it be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. The same API will work for the JavaScript too.